# IIS Rewrite Rule - how to manipulate {HTTP_HOST} string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I've just started using iis rewrite rules for the first time and I'm struggling with what I imagine is an easy rule.

Basically, I wish to use this rule

```
   <rule name="redirect">
      <match url="^(one$|two$|three$)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" /> 
    </rule>
```

But have the redirect {HTTP_HOST} string minus the extension [.co.uk / .com etc.].

e.g.

**bigsite.co.uk/one**

would redirect to:

**bigsite.co.uk/bigsite/one**

How does one go about this - for I can only find Tolower / UrlEncode / UrlDecode string manipulators?

[*Ultimately, I would also like to then use a rewrite rule to hide the fact that the redirect has occurred, i.e. the address would remain as bigsite.co.uk/one after the redirect.*]

Answer (score 1):

Well I eventually came up with this (hope it may help someone):

```
    <rule name="redirect">
      <match url="^(one$|two$|three$)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?(.*).co.uk" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
```

...not sure if there is a better way, but it works perfectly for me - thanks all, PP